# For a BizTalk WCF-SQL adapter in Solicit-Response Send port. How to let adapter handle the response data like XmlPolling?

Tags: sql, biztalk

For a SP using For Xml returns a xml as response, If this sp was consumed by a WCF receive location, we can specify the Polling as XmlPolling to let adapter keep the responsed xml "as-is".  But for a wcf-sql Solicit-Response Send port, It seems no same way to do it. Currently, the best result I can get is let adapter treat the xml response as a CDATA. Like below:

```
<usp_MySPResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/dbo">
<StoredProcedureResultSet0>
    <StoredProcedureResultSet0 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/ProceduresResultSets/dbo/usp_MySP">
        <UnNamedColumn0><![CDATA[ <!-- The XML content of sp returned goes here -->
 ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the Stored Procedure uses the FOR XML clause, there are two binding properties you must set for the result to be recognized as Xml:

- XmlStoredProcedureRootNodeName
- XmlStoredProcedureRootNodeNamespace

It's these two properties that tell the Adapter it's a FOR XML Stored Procedure.  These are essentially the same as the legacy SQL Adapter.

Details here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787898.aspx

There is no way around this so your BizTalk Schema must match these values.

Comment: XmlProcedure. That's what I am looking for.

Comment: Also, read Peter Lindgrens answer below, pointing out most relevant parts to get right.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-sql/execute-stored-procedures-having-a-for-xml-clause-in-sql-server-using-biztalk *carefully*, it says that the request schema must be generated selecting from "Procedures", undeniably not "TypedProcedures". The request message will therefore be in the namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo` which is not explicitly mentioned in 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-sql/message-schemas-for-procedures-and-functions but the action for a "for xml"-typed procedure is specified there.

To summarize: A request message is thus:

```
<YOURSPNAME xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Procedures/dbo" />
```

and the port configuration action header is

```
<BtsActionMapping xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Operation Name="YOURSPNAME" Action="XmlProcedure/dbo/YOURSPNAME" />
</BtsActionMapping>
```

Note the discrepancy between the request message's namespace and the operation action, only the action has "Xml" in it. And don't forget to specify the (FOR XML) binding parameters, as answered by Johns-305.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Still helps people! :)